# Bad json for Firebase data rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

What's wrong with this? It says

> Error saving rules - Line 12: Expected '{'.

Which regards the **.body** line, right after the **:**

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",


        "v1": {
            "v2": {
                "$v3": {
                    "v4": {
                        "$v5": {
                            ".body": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length < 10"  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

**I got it.**

The last part should have been

```
"body": {
    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length < 10"                         
}
```

Comment: can u more describe u r question@jonny

Comment: You appear to be using a dollar sign inconsistently with the `v` keys; is that intentional?

Comment: The JSON you posted is fine (`jq` parses it without error); is this part of a large file?